# Can I use different adapters for different models?

Tags: active-model-serializers

Is it possible to specify different active-model-serializers adapters for different models?

Based on my reading, the gem only seems to allow the initialization of an app-wide adapter.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the adapter like this:

```
 render json: @post, serializer: PostPreviewSerializer, adapter: :json_api
```